# What is the skin effect?

Tags: high-frequency

What is meant by the skin effect?

Comment: @Leon Heller why can't anyone look up most of the questions on this site? This should be the place that people look up the answer to questions.

Comment: @leon heller - sometimes subjects can be hard to approach, especially with regards to theory and nomenclature, it can just be easier to ask someone a question.

Comment: @Jim I gave you a vote because that is true, but users should also attempt to educate themselves before asking the question. **As it stands, this question is a dictionary or encyclopedia lookup**, either of which should satisfactorily answer the question, and possibly produce a more refined question. Frankly I didn't find Thomas' answer so accessible or accurate, and in the end he simply linked to [the first Google hit for the term](http://www.google.com/search?q=skin+effect).

Comment: @Kellenjb (and @jim) (continued) **This is called a "lazy" question** and it is generally agreed that it is wiser to spend our resources (brainpower, knowledge, experience, and time) on providing answers to more difficult and useful questions. Also see [Area51 FAQs](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) (search for "expert[ise]" and the design principle of a StackExchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create) (click in the second text area to see the fade-in text).

Comment: @MarK C, These are not reasons to close a question, if you dislike it, a downvote is a fair course of action. remember a major thing we need to do to bring users in is become a definitive source for the basic and challenging questions, an all in one source for information. If the answer seems poor, answer in a better way. I think this question was answered by someone whom normally asks questions and gave this user a chance to be the 'expert'. As the question becomes easier, the group that answers it should move to those that are not as experienced but know those basics.

Comment: @Mark C, while not calling your electronics knowledge into question Mark (I'm sure mine is much lower), really Thomas didn't just "link to google" as you assert. Certainly wiki link is the first link on google, however his answer is worded differently and he met my goal of asking the question which was to present the answer in an accessible form to a layperson. This topic (electronics and robots) in particular has alot of interest from sections of the public that do not have university level electronics/mechatronics knowledge. Maybe you should remember that. :)

Comment: @Kortuk I said nothing about "closing the question". As I have [pointed out above](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), The designers of StackExchange [disagree](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create); these sites are not intended to be "all-in-one sources of information", but sources of expertise, rather. I do not know if you were just guessing, but Thomas is certainly not "just someone who normally asks questions", let alone basic ones.

Comment: @Anon No, in honesty, my knowledge of low-level (i.e. micro) electronics is scant, but this is a physics question. Please be accurate; I did not "merely assert" he linked to Google. Please note, as you and Kortuk seem to have overlooked, that **my point (though not emphasized) is that a little bit of research would produce a refined and more useful question, which would contain this question as a basic element.** We are not competing with Wikipedia; there are untold peta(?)bytes of unrefined information on the Internet.

Comment: @Mark C, the way you came across you were asking to close it. I would agree with a little research this could be a better question. I am very active on this site and Thomas O normally asks questions, for this he got to answer one. I have had discussions with the guys that are paid to keep SO running and they intend the site to be an all in one source for google results and such. In an ideal world when you google something related to E&R you would get one of our questions and answers.

Comment: @All, point taken Mark I will try to improve my questions, but at the same time I won't shy away from asking questions especially when I believe that I can get more value from an answer here than on reading a wiki post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The skin effect is a usually undesirable effect which occurs when using AC signals. It causes the outer surface - the "skin" of the wire - to be used more than the inner surface for carrying current - engineers say the surface has a higher "current density", or amperes per meter squared. This causes an increase in the effective resistance of the wire.

Because the outer surface must carry more current the wire is more expensive, because you can't get rid of the inner surface easily. In electrical power distribution, the skin effect is very important, because it decides the type and thickness of the wire you use.

Skin depth reduces at higher frequencies. Carrying a 50 Hz signal takes less wire than a 1 kHz signal, for example. Skin depth also varies with the type of wire.

[See here for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect).

Comment: from wikipedia:At 60 Hz in copper, skin depth is about 8.5 mm. this means as you pass this depth the extra thickness does not help.

Comment: @Kortuk Maybe I am misunderstanding, but wouldn't extra thickness help because it's increasing the circumference of the wire, which should increase the total cross-sectional conductive area even if it only penetrates to 8.5mm?

Comment: @Chuu - skin depth tells you how much of your wire will be used. Yes, increasing the diameter will increase the circumference, so affects the conductivity even at a higher frequency, but the gains are greatly diminishing. The highlight of 8.5mm is to point out at a frequency as low as 60Hz, which is very low compared to the modern world, the amount of the wire used has already been drastically limited.

Answer (score 7):

The skin effect means that the current of AC signals will be concentrated near the surface, the "skin", of a conductor. The higher the frequency the thinner this layer. For very high frequencies it's no use to have a massive conductor; the core wouldn't carry current. Hence for HF braided copper wires are used, which have a larger combined surface.

Answer (score 3):

At very high AC frequencies, basically RF, all the current goes through the "skin". In radar systems, we use hollow wave guides instead of solid conductors.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find a physical explanation which is using maxwells law. 
[link to physics.stackoverflow](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5628/skin-effect-and-currents)